# How to defer offscreen images in Shopify?

Tags: optimization, shopify, minify, pagespeed

According to Google PageSpeed Insights, defer offscreen image is taking >10sec to load a page. I want to know how to handle/fix this issue in the coding section. I think it it can be done by using media queries but HOW?

I have already compressed images and adjust images dimensions.

My page speed is 10/100 for mobile and 65/100 for desktop.

"https://withambience.com/collections/all-time-favorites/products/royalwinterleggings"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend lazy loading your images. Here's a [quick tutorial](http://shopifyexplorer.com/add-lazy-load-image-shopify-theme.html) that uses the lazysizes library. And here's a more general [optimization article](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/18840023-how-to-optimize-themes-for-performance) from the shopify team. Best of luck.